# Why I can't use if statements in except statements?

Tags: python, if-statement, except, statements

Why can't I add an `if` statement in except statements?

I want to show both forms of this kind of error in the output:

```
try:
    t = int(input("How time need: "))
except ValueError:
    if type(t) == float:
        print(">>> you should give a int number (you given float) <<<\n")
    elif type(t) == str:
        print(">>> you should give a int number (you given str) <<<\n")
```

Comment: why you can't do that? what is the error? and what is t?

Comment: Why would you use the `except`? The `if` and `elif` clause will be catching the exception with that logic.

Comment: @CeliusStingher in general it's faster to just run the code and worry about exceptions only when they are generated. If they are not, you just saved two branches.

Comment: You can; that's not your problem. `t == x` is not the way to check if `t` is a value of type `x`.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem isn't that you can't put `if` in your `except`. The code you gave should run just fine. However, it won't do what you think it does. I suspect your code contains something like:

```
t = input('>>>')
```

In this case `t` will always be a string. But if you say

```
if t == float:
    print(">>> you should give a int number (you given float) <<<\n")
elif t == str:
    print(">>> you should give a int number (you given str) <<<\n")
```

This won't print anything. Why? `t` does not equal a string, it an object of string type. So instead check:

```
if isinstance(t, float):
    print(">>> you should give a int number (you given float) <<<\n")
elif isinstance(t, str):
    print(">>> you should give a int number (you given str) <<<\n")
```

Comment: Oh boy, nice read of potential XY problem there. I assumed `t` was already `type(x)` for some `x = input()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional logic such as `if` statements in `except` blocks:

```py
try:
  raise ValueError("asd")
except ValueError as e:
  if someVal == 10:
    print("someval is 10")
  elif someVal == 20:
    print("someval is 10")
```

[Try it here](https://repl.it/repls/VoluminousMeaslyByte)

However, if you want to check on the type of a variable, use `type`:

```py
if type(myVar) == int:
    print("myVar is an integer")
```

In your case, to check which type your variable has, something along those lines would work:

```py
#myVar = 10          #comment in the appropiate line
myVar = "a string"

try:
  # some work which might raise a ValueError
  raise ValueError()
except ValueError:
  if type(myVar) == int:
    print("myVar is an int.")
  elif type(myVar) == str:
    print("myVar is a string.")
```

Another (and probably better) way to check for a specific type is by using `isinstance`. See the answer from Nathan for more info on that.

Comment: use `==` not `is` to compare integers

Comment: You should (usually) use `isinstance` to check if an object is of a specific type: https://premaseem.wordpress.com/2017/10/11/python-difference-between-type-and-isinstance/

Comment: @Nathan yep, thats true. But I assume, type() is fine if someone wants to check for _primitive_ types?

Comment: @Hafnernuss of course, but since OP is still learning, these distinctions may be important

Comment: I have added a reference to your answer @Nathan.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
try:
    t = int(input("How time need: "))
except ValueError as e:

    if isinstance(_,float):
        print(">>> you should give a int number (you given float) <<<\n")
    elif isinstance(_,str):
        print(">>> you should give a int number (you given str) <<<\n")
```

The error was raised before `t` was getting created, hence the error. We know python stores last input/answer in `_` so hence used this.  :)

Comment: what error do you get ? and can you share the try block also

Comment: How time need give factorial: n vjcbvxv
How time need give factorial: 8.9978
How time need give factorial: 9
#CHANGE TIMES = 0
Start
You'r times: 9 

Enter a number:

Comment: I have checked it by running it on my side and it works fine for me. What error are you facing ?